# Couldn't browse the website which is created by sharepoint central administration

Tags: sharepoint

This isn't a programming issue base on sharepoint, as a common user, I just created a web application in sharepoint central administration v4 in windows server 2012. After that the site was set up in IIS but I couldn't browse it in IE.

I think there should be an empty website base on existing template when generating in sharepoint, it should be show normally even if I didn't edit the website content.

This is the first time that I deploy it, how should I config it next step?

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a normal user you cannot create a web application. People with access to the central administration are called administrators ;)

So SharePoint did not create a Sitecollection for you. No Problem. Create one yourself. Either in Central administration or on Powershell. If there is no Sitecollection on your root path `http://yourservername`, you should be able to create one there.

```
#assuming you want to create the SiteCollection on your root path.
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"
New-SPSite -Url "http://yourserverurl/" -OwnerAlias "domain\user" -Template $template
```

**/EDIT:**
I have just created a WebApplication myself to recreate your problem and as it turns out, this is not a problem.

> If this is the first time that you have used this application pool
>   with a SharePoint Web application, you must wait until the Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) Web site has been created on all servers.
>   **By default, no new SharePoint site collections are created with the
>   Web application.** If you have just created a Forms Based Authentication
>   (FBA) Web application, then before creating a new site collection, you
>   will need to perform some additional configuration steps.

This is what you can read after yuor WebApplication has been created. So you definitly need to create a SiteCollection under your WebApplication yourself, before you can start browsing. If you do not create a Sitecollection prior to calling the URL to your WebApplication, the best result you can get is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Wed, 21 May 2014 07:47:38 GMT
Connection: close
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks Serv! I skipped reading the prompt after creating the new web application. Instead of using the above script command, I've created a  site collection for the specified web application, it works pretty good!

Comment: Here is another unknown issue, I tried running the above script in powershell as admin but failed. I googled it and found that many guys encountered it too, "New-SPSite : Cannot find an SPWebApplication object that contains the following Name, Id...", the destination server address I specified is http://localhost:<portNO.>, I'm sure that the port number is unused and didn't find the solution. Finally I created it in sharepoint central admin in browser.